# What was the Linux console command to add on one user read and exec permission, and to other them too but with writing permission too?

Tags: linux, command-line, desktop-computer, console, command-line-arguments

Need help for the question in topic.

I am trying to add these permissions for users on my practice project.

I forgot what was the command for it. :(

Answer (score -1):

Command is mostly **chmod** See related man pages

Comment: While this answer does the mention the command to control file permissions, it does not answer the user's question, and it leaves them to have to do more research that shouldn't be necessary. Please don't let laziness affect your answer quality.